# Manga where a magician buys a house, and it has a talking house spirit (girl)

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I'm very sorry, all I can remember is that he stores his house spirit in this magic crystal, and moves his house using a storage dimension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty sure this is *[A Sage Is Summoned to Another World: The Undesired Items Are Now the Strongest](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=156799)*.

[image]

> Touya, the strongest player in the game Pandemic World Online, has won so many items that he decided to create an alternative account to store them, while playing he was summoned to another world, but not having the category of hero is discarded and replaced by another person, now he will have to survive only in that world and with the character he created to store those items.

The main character, Touya Kisaragi, is a mage who buys a mansion with a female house spirit in it. (She's initially silent, but starts talking a bit later.) He also has a "dimensional storage" facility, within which he stores many items, including a house. He subsequently acquires a "spirit crystal stone", within which he can carry his house spirit.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and that is the one I was looking for.

Comment: I'm really curious as to how you managed to find it with so little information.

Comment: @Clockwork - I stumbled upon [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/k0rzj1/looking_for_a_certain_isekai_manga/), where someone asked about the same manga. I had to skim through 14 chapters to confirm the presence of everything mentioned in the question though.